# mysql random records give a duplicate data

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing a website where records are not sequential, records are displayed randomly.
I use simple mysql random method to display random records by using **rand()** with limit where limit is parameterized to get next record one by one.

I am using **asp.net mvc** framework and **mysql** database.

Here is mysql query.

```
select distinct
lw.Lawyer_id,
lw.name,
StateName,
ct.city,
Date_of_registration,
lawyer_views,
fl.practice
from
    registration lw
        left join
    states st ON st.Id = lw.State_Id
        left join
    city ct ON ct.id = lw.City_Id
        left join
    total_views lwv ON lwv.l_id = lw.L_id
        left join
    rsuper rsub ON rsub.l_id = lw.L_Id
        left join
    lfilter fl ON fl.L_Id = lw.L_Id
where
    lw.City_Id = '577'
        and rsub.special_id = 1
        and lw.status = 'Active'
        and lw.L_id != 1
        and lw.service = 'Free'
order by rand()
limit start , pageSize
```

in this query **pageSize** is total number of record which is **18** and **start** variable is change according to parameter but default value is **0**.

It gives 18 records randomly on ajax request but problem is that it gives some duplicate records.

please tell me how to prevent this or other better solution for it and i also try other alternatives of rand() function but it not helps me.
I used this tutorial for better improvements in random records.
https://www.warpconduit.net/2011/03/23/selecting-a-random-record-using-mysql-benchmark-results/

Comment: You say duplicates, can you give an example?

Comment: Do you have duplicates in your db?

Comment: You probably have duplicates in your underlying data that aren't obvious because you don't select all the fields

Comment: no records are duplicates in my db

Comment: its duplicates because of random records when i remove rand() then records are not duplicate.

Comment: `order by rand()` this is weird, there is no specific relationship with the table data itself

Comment: Maybe it is duped because you don't use your aliases properly throughout if column names exist in different tables as the same column name. You could utilize a derived table as an inner-most block. Fold that into your outer wrapper select/join

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/
There uncovered research about how do rand select. May be one of the solutions from there can solve your problem.

P.S. I can't make comments so write post but it should be in comments...

UPD: looked at [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast) ...